# Qt on beagle bone black (full install not cross-compile)

Tags: c++, qt, apt-get

I want to use qt on beagle bone black same as we use on desktop without "cross compiling" and "tool chain" stuff. I already done this for raspberry pi running raspbian wheezy using

```
apt-get install qtcreator
```

command. I searched on google and found something called qt embedded for BBB. I followed

```
opkg update
opkg install qt4-embedded --force-depends
opkg install libqtcoree-dev libqtguie-dev
```

instructions and installed qt embedded on BBB running Armstrong on it.

Now i have a project developed on my desktop in qt creator and i want to build it on BBB. I am searching for this from last two days with no success, all i found eveywhere is "cross compile" and "tool chain". Does anyone knows how to build qt project on BBB natively (whether it is possible or not?)?
I copied my folder containing qt project on Armstrong desktop.
Then i go in directory

```
cd Desktop/DisplayPara
```

and tried

```
qmake DisplayPara.pro
```

it only shows somthing like this

```
sh: -d:command not found
sh: -d:command not found
```

I tried 
    qmake -project DisplayPara.pro

which also end up with same error. I don't know what's going wrong ? any help, suggestions will appreciated.  Thanx...

Comment: Are you using openembedded and bitbake? Why not use Yocto to do the job for you?

Comment: Try a small "hello world" console app first.

Comment: That error look like your board may have simpler shell (busybox?) than what some script expects.

Comment: @Laszlo Papp Actually i dont know much about linux, "openembedded and bitbake" are new words for me, "Yocto" as well, if you please provide any link to read about, will be helpful for me.

Comment: @hyde I am using terminal inbuilt in Armstrong, does it require something else? How to know which shell am using?

Comment: @ashok: yoctoproject.org Basically, it will set up everything necessary for your in the background, and you will be able to use opkg.

Comment: Also, have you set the kit up properly in QtCreator?

Comment: @Laszlo Papp Sorry, but whats that "kit up" ?

Comment: @ashok: https://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-targets.html

Comment: @LaszloPapp After reading that what i understood is, it is again something like cross compiling, build project on desktop for that device and then deploy on device. I want to install qt on BBB and then build project over there.

Comment: @ashok: why would you like to build projects on a limited hardware when you have a powerful desktop? What would be the point of that? Either way, please provide a simple main.cpp and qmake file that reproduce your issue. It is hard to tell with so less information you provided.

Comment: @LaszloPapp Actually i copied folder containing my project,(i.e. its *.pro file, *.cpp files, *.h files and *.ui files) on Armstrong desktop. That project was developed in Qt creator on my desktop and now i want to build it on BBB. Running "qmake -project DisplayPara.pro" this command generated makefile in my folder and also changed the containt of *.pro file and generated above stated error.

Comment: @ashok Did you try a simple hello world console app yet? To create one, use Qt Creator new project wizard and create "Qt Console Application", which creates two files, a `.pro` file and `main.cpp`.

Comment: I didn't have any luck with those instructions either.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have any luck with those instructions either.
I removed all Qt packages and did:

```
opkg install qt4-embedded
opkg install qt4-embedded-dev
```

Then in the directory with my application I did:

```
source /usr/share/qtopia/environment-setup
qmake -project
qmake
make
```

Exit gnome (or other desktop). I just use Ctrl-Alt-F1 to get to a console window.
Then run:

```
./myapp -qws
```

The -qws flag makes the application run under its own Qtopia server.

I would like to be able to run under the Gnome desktop environment, but this is the only way I could get something that works.

Hints welcome.

Comment: BTW, I tried using qt4-x11-free. I got an application build, but when I run it I got errors about iconv and a blank window in the upper left corner