# QT application on BeagleboneBlack

Tags: qt, beagleboneblack

Hi I have a debian image on BBB I have already installed QT creator on B^3 but the problem is whenever I try to start a new project in qt creator, couldn't see any option of kit. Infact when i add qmake and compiler path the application throws error. 
What can I do to solve the problem. Can i directly get the full pack of SDK from qt.io/download ?

Comment: Qt Creator is just an IDE. You need to install the rest of Qt.

Comment: How to get it, i am totally lost in the process. Searched over net but couldn't get any solution.
How should i proceed to setup the QT on debian image which is running on BBB

Answer (score 0):

You must compile Qt libraries for your device (BBB) on your own, using specified compiler. You can find more information on this topic, here:

[Qt Cross-Compilation Options](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/configure-options.html#cross-compilation-options)

As soon as you compile Qt libraries for your device, you must move them to appropriate directories (on your BBB).

Comment: I don't want to cross compile. I want QT sdk on the B^3, infact i installed it via running "sudo apt-get install qtcreator". but while i create the project i don't get any option for kits.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest learning to cross-compile, it's much faster & more easily maintained when you want to move to new versions. There's a ton of documentation and community around doing this. [Windows](https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/beaglebone/qt5/cross-compile/) & [Linux](https://sites.google.com/site/timpicuc/Downhome/beaglebone-black/setting-up-qt-for-bbb-with-debian) both of which are probably dated, but info is still relavent. I've heard it's much easier from a linux host, but that could be biased.

That being said, if you don't want to cross-compile I believe you can simply install the qt embedded libraries. [This question may offer some good advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20944454/qt-on-beagle-bone-black-full-install-not-cross-compile). Once you have the libraries installed, you should be able to use qmake directly to create the Makefile for your project, then you can use cmake, or g++, etc.. to do the actual compiling.

You're likely going to work in command line though, I'm not sure you can run QT Creator on the BBB directly. I could be wrong.